# Adobe Reader XI preferences dialog is "all messed up"

Tags: adobe-reader

In Adobe Reader XI, if I click on "Edit" and then "Preferences", the screen that pops up is displaying wrong information. It has an apply button without "Apply" written in. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Adobe Reader. It's possible that the installation is corrupt.